# Как достать наименование таблицы из массива?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8

Имеется массив, где объединены 2 таблицы sql. Есть ли возможность достать значение поля "table"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице поиска выводится интересующая пользователя информация из двух таблиц: "products" - товары и "blogs" = блоги.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я связал между собой таблицы через merge следующим образом:

```html
$rsltSearch = $request->searchAll;//результат поиска
$product = Products::query()->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$rsltSearch}%")->get();
$blog = blog::query()->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$rsltSearch}%")->get();
$searchAll = $product->merge($blog);//связь таблиц product и blog
```

Но столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Т.к. у пользователя есть возможность перейти по выбранной ссылке, нужно сделать проверку перенаправления для двух роутов.

```html
@foreach($searchAll as $item)
  <div class="product-wrapper mb-10">
    <div class="product-list-content">
       @if($item['table'] == 'product')
           <a href="{{route('pet-shop.dropuct-details',$item->id)}}">{{$item->name}}</a>
            **pet-shop-dropuct-details - страница товара**
       @else
           <a href="{{route('blog-details',$item->id)}}">{{$item->name}}</a>
            **blog-details - страница блога**
       @endif
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Я пытаюсь это сделать через значение массива "table", для проверки "если table == "product"" то выводит для него требуемый роут.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод [`getTable`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getTable):

```php
// products
$table = $product->getTable();
```

Comment: $product = Products::class;
$table = $product->getTable();
Всё ведь верно сделал?

Comment: @Kugasu `$product` -- это экземпляр модели. Приведите в вопрос пример того, как вы выводите информацию о товаре на страницу, и я смогу подсказать вам

Comment: Сделал как вы и просили